# C# Compiled Application -> Right Click -> Run As Different User -> Crash

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crash, runas

I've created a new solution with just the code from wizard:

```
namespace TesteOpenWithDifferentUser
{
    static class Program
    {       
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

I compile and open the output folder "...project\bin\Debug", there I try to open my application with a different user "[Shift] + Right Click -> Run as different user". I type another user and, instead of opening my application it crash and show a message like this:

... application directory ...

The specified path does not exist.

Check path and then try again.

---

I have already read about Impersonation, privileges and UseShellExecute, but nothing (until now) solved my problem. I think this can't be so difficult, but I can't make it work.

Comment: I'd guess your app is in a folder such as your desktop, locked down to your current user. When you impersonate a new user, it tries to run the app but cannot access your original user's profile folders (typically C:\Users\You).

Comment: Haney, I'm not using any impersonation, I just [shift] right click on .exe and then Run as different user. Besides, the application is in a public network directory.

Comment: Does the other user have access to that network directory?

Comment: Yes, the other login is from a coworker, we have the same rights.

Comment: Plus: If the application is located in my "C:\App", I can use the "Run as different user" without any problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Event Viewer to see why it crashed? Often there will be exception information there under Application.

Comment: Show us some code from the ctor() of Form1. I wonder if it crashes in there.

Comment: Haney, unfortunately there isn't any log in Event Viewer that contains the name or something directly related to my application, but, I suspect that this log can be envolved with my problem (or not, because I just realize that it log is created in the same time that the error occurs):
1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-449001997-539056922-2858533467-10133_Classes: Process 76 (\Device\HarddiskVolume5\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-449001997-539056922-2858533467-10133_CLASSES

Comment: Matt, the constructor of Form1 is the generated one:
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

Comment: Plus:
1) If i put the application in some shared directory in my computer and access it in my workmate computer, it works.
2) If I access the application using: \\myserver01\App\App.exe it works.
3) If I access using \\domain.local\data\App\App.exe it works.
4) But, If access using G:\App\App.exe it not work. (G is my network drive)